# My thrift ./configure does not building python library

Tags: python, thrift

I am new to thrift,trying to install it in my mac.so I download a new version 0.9.3, run `./configure`. But the output is below:

```
thrift 0.9.3

Building C++ Library ......... : yes
Building C (GLib) Library .... : no
Building Java Library ........ : yes
Building C# Library .......... : no
Building Python Library ...... : no
Building Ruby Library ........ : no
Building Haxe Library ........ : no
Building Haskell Library ..... : no
Building Perl Library ........ : yes
Building PHP Library ......... : yes
Building Erlang Library ...... : no
Building Go Library .......... : no
Building D Library ........... : no
Building NodeJS Library ...... : no
Building Lua Library ......... : no
```

but, in fact it has checked python env successfully as below:

```
checking for a Python interpreter with version >= 2.4... python
checking for python... /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
checking for python version... 2.7
checking for python platform... darwin
checking for python script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python2.7/site-packages
checking for python extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

what else do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

don't know if it can help (old post), but in 0.9.3, configure script checks for trial & python existence in order to decide if python library has to be built => check if trial is available, or install python-twisted in order to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`python` must be in path. Test it by `which python`

And then check `PYTHONPATH`, it should be:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
or 
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
or
other custom path
```

Comment: I needed this as well. http://blog.intelligencecomputing.io/middleware/869/install-thrift-on-linux